# How to create an event button on a background object tag

Tags: javascript, html, button, javascript-objects, dom-events

I would like to create an html button with SVG animations in the background, with the label and CSS styles I get an interesting effect, but I cannot give events with Javascript to the tag `"<object"`

https://codepen.io/jose-manuel-mateos/pen/WNrGWGy

````
<object  onclick="cambioslaider()" class="botoninicio" data="https://animacionesweb.online/animaciones/pecera.svg"></object>
     .botoninicio {
                       color: #ffffff;
                     border-radius: 18px;
                    background: #303030;
                    width:100px;
                    height:50px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                        margin:3px;
                 background: #303030;
                border: 2px solid #0016b0;
                }    ```   


                function cambioslaider(){
                    console.log("me llaman");
                    alert("me llaman");

                }
````